# Django models for multiple foreign keys and getting inputs through forms

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many, modelform

I'm trying to build SCM models that involve multiple layers of foreignkeys, and then get inputs for them in one form. For example, when a purchase order is made, it may contain multiple products which may ship in multiple shipments. A shipment is defined as a group of containers with same origin and destination leaving on the same date under one trade documentation. Each container may contain multiple products, and in rare cases, inventory for one product may belong to multiple purchase orders. A container cannot belong to more than one shipment. What would be the best way to structure these relationships? And how can I use one template to get input using forms and save them via view?

Below is some of the relationship I tried to build. I'm not sure if this class and relationships are the best designs. Any feedback on overall structure would be greatly appreciated. If I want to collect information on purchase order and related shipments, containers, and products in one HTML template, how should I use the Django forms?

Here is some pseudo code for example:

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    issuedBy = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    issuedAt = models.DateTimeField()

class Shipment(models.Model):
    purchaseOrder = models.ManyToManyField('PurchaseOrder')
    origin = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name='origin_for')
    destination = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name = 'destination_for')
    shippedAt = models.DateTimeField()

class Shipment_Container(models.Model):
    shipment = models.ForeignKey('Shipment')
    containerType = models.ForeignKey('ContainerType')
    loadType = models.ForeignKey('LoadType')

class Shipment_Container_Product(models.Model):
    shipment_container = models.ForeignKey('Shipment_Container')
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: You can't ask "how should I code this" on SO. It also seems to me that it's a very difficult UI to do in one page. But maybe you got a design by your product manager. But I would first think in terms of UI to understand what forms are needed and how the data will be submitted.

Comment: also, use **plural** when the relationship represents many objects: `purchase_orders = ManyToManyField...`. And remember the related name is for the **reverse** relationship and should be **plural** as well, so a better related name for `origin` would be `departing_shipments` and for `destination` `arriving_shipments` so you can do `some_address.departing_shipments.all()`.

Comment: I would use multiple forms on a horizontal slide system. IE: form1 is Purchase Order on slide one of the html page. Then you click next, sending an Ajax request, and if validated, the HTML let's you scroll. If not, a JSON response gives an error message. This should keep it tidy and comprehensible at the same time,